# How Handle Null Values(In Columns) In Telerik RadGrid? (Replace With HTML)

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, telerik, radgrid

i have a BooundColumn in my telerik RadGrid like below :

```
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" FilterControlAltText="Filter Status column"
                        HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status"
                        FilterImageToolTip="Filter">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Status Column in my sql server 2008 database can accept null values and RadGrid shows them with an empty string.
how can i replace these `Empty Strings` with a `Colorable Strings`?
mean replacement with something like this -> `<span style='color: red;'>Empty</span>`
i know i can convert that BoundColumn to TemplateColumn like this :

```
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Status column"
                            HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Status" FilterImageToolTip="Filter"
                            ReadOnly="False" Visible="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatusInsideGrd" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Text='<%# (bool)Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Status")) ? "<span class=\"lblInsideGrd\">Empty</span>" : Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

this replacement is a good idea and works great. but by doing that i lose RadGrid `Filering` on this column.
would you please showe me another way with keeping RadGrid Friltering?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that on ItemDataBound event, when grid is binded to SqlDataSource as in your case you can get current DataRow :

**Update**: I leaved just code that works with DataRow, and fix column background setting

```
public void TestGrid_ItemDataBound(Object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
  {
    if (e.Item.DataItem is DataRowView)
    {
      GridDataItem gdItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
      DataRow rw = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
      if (rw.IsNull("Status"))
      {
        GridColumn urlColumn = TestGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("Status");
        gdItem.Cells[urlColumn.OrderIndex].BackColor = Color.Red;
        gdItem["Status"].Text = "Empty";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT BY QUESTIONER**
Really thanks for these codes.
the codes below are ok for me :

```
protected void grdSMS_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        if (item["Status"].Text == "&nbsp;")
        {
            item["Status"].ForeColor = Color.Red;
            item["Status"].Text = "Empty";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how can i change that item's text(value) to "Empty"?

Comment: dear bro, nothing happens by your way #1 and by way #2 all columns(including data columns -> not null, including other than Status columns) become red. what is the problem?

Comment: did you set onitemdatabound grid event to that method (RadGrid1_ItemDataBound) ?

Comment: Well I tried it and it works, set break point in that event and see what is happening

Comment: thanks for the edit -> this line has error ->  e.Item["Status"].Text = "Empty"; (Way 2)

Comment: Error 24 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem' F:\Programming\SMS.aspx.cs

Comment: sorry fixed, that has to GridDataItem so we need to cast it

Comment: man way #1 does not work and by way #2 all columns are red. we should change null columns not the entire rows. besides that Empty string does not work. so confused about this situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11957/discussion-between-antonio-bakula-and-moonlight)

Comment: Now Every Thing Is Ok - Thanks For Update.